# css hover : aligning on bottom: how to align on top?

Tags: css, css-float

[image: Before]

[image: on rollover]

and here is the css:

```
.divPhoto {
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    transition:0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.divPhoto:hover {
    border:1px solid #0000FF;
    background-color:#CCC;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:175px;
}



foreach($photos as $photo) { ?>

    <div class="divPhoto" >
        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="upload/<?=$photo->filename?>"><img class="img-polaroid" src="upload/thumb/<?=$photo->filename?>"></a>
        <input type="button" class="btn btnEffacer" value="effacer" style="margin-left:30px;" data="<?=$photo->id?>" />
    </div> 


<? } ?>
```

ANy idea on align the hover on bottom and not on top ?
Because now all pictures are moving when hovering an imahe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `vertical-align:top` to the `.divPhoto` rule should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since you change the height on hover from 140px to 175px, you need some extra margin-bottom on the unhovered state to pad it out to 175px height.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `display:inline-table;` for `.divPhoto` div

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGQaU/1/)**

```
.divPhoto {
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    display:inline-table;  /* <= this line */
    margin:10px;
    transition:0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements are inline-blocks, you can simply use `vertical-align: top`:

```
.divPhoto {
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    transition:0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtejn/